# Threading.Timer(5, function) launch every 5 second

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading

I'm having a hard hard time with `Timer` function from threading.

Basically, when my program starts, I want to log stats every x second.

So I thought I could do it with the `Timer` function (launch function every 5 second).

For now, I did :

```
from threading import Timer
def startLogger():
    while True:
        t = Timer(5, function)
        t.start()


def function():
    print("hey")
```

But it launch error, so I think it's not the good way to do it.

`RuntimeError: can't start new thread`

If someone can give me a clue, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following. The idea is, that you are scheduling the next function call just at the end of this function's body:

```
import threading

def mylog():
  print "hey"
` threading.Timer(5.0, mylog)`.start()

mylog()
```

Comment: not applicable to functions that take more than 5 sec to execute

Answer (score 11):

Instead of starting a new thread every five seconds, you can create just one thread and run all your code from there.

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def startLogger():
    while True:
        function()
        sleep(5)

def function():
    print("hey")

Thread(target=startLogger).start()
```

`startLogger` will continually run. It'll call `function`, then pause for 5 seconds, then start again, calling `function` and so on.

It goes in its own thread so that the `sleep(5)` doesn't also stop your main thread for 5 seconds.

Comment: not working if function() takes more than 5 seconds to execute

Comment: @Cris It still works: the `while` loop in `startLogger` will take 5 seconds + however long it takes `function()` to execute to finish one iteration. If `function()` takes 6 seconds to run, the loop will take 5+6=11 seconds to run, but `function()` will still be called five seconds after it finished executing. — If you really want `function` to be started *exactly* every five seconds, regardless of the amount of time it takes to execute, you can just replace `function()` with `Thread(target=function).start()` to run `function` in its own thread, separate from the `while` loop's thread.

Comment: I see... threading makes total sense. In my case function() takes a variable amount of time (<5 sec most of the time except when going over 5sec). The loop must be executed every 5 sec regardless.